# Matrix representation with respect to the column space basis

Tags: matrices

Consider the $3$ by $3$ matrix
    $$
 A=
 \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 4 \\
 3 & 6 & 12 \\
 1 & 5 & 7
 \end{bmatrix}
 $$
    and the linear transformation $T_A : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by
    $$
 {\bf y} =T_A({\bf x}) = A{\bf x}
 $$
    where ${\bf x}, {\bf y}$ are in the standard coordinates.
    Let 
    $$
 \begin{array}{cccc}
 F:&C(A^{\mathrm T}) &\to &C(A) \\
 &{\bf x}_r     &\mapsto &A{\bf x}_r 
 \end{array}
 $$
    be the restriction of $T_A$. We will examine this linear transformation from the row space to the column space.

Confirm that rank A=2, hence $\dim C(A^{\mathrm T}) = \dim C(A) =2$.

Find a basis $\langle {\bf v}_1, {\bf v}_2 \rangle$ for $C(A^{\mathrm T})$ and a basis $\langle {\bf w}_1, {\bf w}_2 \rangle$ for $C(A)$.

Find the matrix representation $B$ of $F:C(A^{\mathrm T}) \to C(A)$ with respect to the bases $\langle {\bf v}_1, {\bf v}_2 \rangle$ and $\langle {\bf w}_1, {\bf w}_2 \rangle$ in Part~(b). Namely, find the $2$ by $2$ matrix $B$ that satisfies
        $$
  \begin{bmatrix}
  F({\bf v}_1) & F({\bf v}_2)
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
  {\bf w}_1 & {\bf w}_2
  \end{bmatrix}
  B.
  $$

I have been stuck on finding the matrix representation.

Comment: What do you denote $C(A^T)$ and $C(A)$?

Comment: For the first column of $B$: Compute $Av_1$ and represent it as a linear combination $c_1w_1+c_2w_2$ of $w_1$ and $w_2$. Then $\binom{c_1}{c_2}$ is your first column.

Comment: @Bernard "Column space" appears once in the title and twice in the question.

Comment: I understand the steps of find the first column or second column, but as I set up the equation $c_1w_1$ + $c_2w_2$ = F($v_1$), what is the other side F($v_1$) should be, in order to solve $c_1$ and $c_2$. @amsmath

Comment: I solve for $\langle {\bf v}_1, {\bf v}_2 \rangle$ = {(1 2 4), (1 5 7)} and $\langle {\bf w}_1, {\bf w}_2 \rangle$ = {(1 3 1), (2 6 5)}. @Bernard

Comment: @D.dream It would be better for you to read my text. I wrote "Compute $Av_1$". Can you do that?

Comment: @amsmath My apologies, but that's what I thought originally, however as I set up the system to solve $c_1$ and $c_2$, I end up with $c_1$ + 2$c_2$ = 21, 3$c_1$ + 6$c_2$ = 63 and $c_1$ + 5$c_2$ = 39. Which doesn't seem right for me since it has 3 equations but only 2 variables.

Comment: The first two are one and the same equation. So, you have actually two.

Answer (score 0):

Compute $Av_1$ and $Av_2$, and write each in terms of $\{w_1,w_2\}$. Those will be your columns.   I get $c_1=6,c_2=9$ (you did most of this in the comments).

Next $c_3+2c_4=39$ and $c_3+5c_4=75$.  We get $c_3=15,c_4=12$.

So $\begin {pmatrix}6&15\\9&12\end {pmatrix}$ is the matrix.